Getting the correct Year to date last year value
I have a table with sales per item per date and i want to add a year to date measure with DAX. Now in Excel what i used to do is add a YTD column which checks if the date (without the year) is in the constraints of the year to date range and return a 0 or a 1. This made it possible to sum the year to date values for this year and the previous years.
Now in DAX i do not now how to get it working, i tried this one but did only give a total ytd result on each date line.
DAX Last Year to Date
What i want to achieve is the below table but with sales ytd not as a total and the sales YTD LY also not as a total.

This is my sales ytd formula that contains al the relevant columns i guess
Sales YTD = 
VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Input Analysefile'[Date]), ALL('Input Analysefile'))
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(MaxDate)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Input Analysefile'[Omzet]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Input Analysefile'[Date]),
        YEAR('Input Analysefile'[Date]) = CurrentYear &&
        'Input Analysefile'[Date] <= MaxDate &&
        'Input Analysefile'[Date] >= DATE(CurrentYear, 1, 1)
    )
)


Hello, have you tried the DAX dates functions ? DATESYTD, SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR, TOTALYTD ?
